# Display of complement as a decimal

Tags: verilog

I am working a Verilog project for a digital design class and my project was to create a calculator that, amongst other things, takes the complement of a 16b signed input and displays it in decimal form in the monitor in the simulator.

This is my test bench monitor:

```
$monitor ("opCode(%b),in1(%d),in2(%d),result(%d),overflow(%b)", opCode, in1, in2, result, overflow);
```

I cannot get the simulator to display the complement of my input in negative decimal representation. Is this just something the simulator wont show, or an issue with the `$monitor`? All other results are being displayed as a decimal correctly.

The result displays like the below output. It shows the complement result displayed as 65526, which should be a -10. The results above and below are displayed correctly 15 and 11 respectively.

```
opCode(0111),in1(10),in2(5),result(15),overflow(0)
opCode(1000),in1(10),in2(5),result(65526),overflow(1)
opCode(1001),in1(10),in2(5),result(11),overflow(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring `result` as `signed`.

`reg signed [15:0] result;`

(See [In verilog printing signed integer value stored in a variable of type reg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324706/in-verilog-printing-signed-integer-value-stored-in-a-variable-of-type-reg))